# Type punning two types from different third party libraries without union

Tags: c++

I've read that using unions for type punning is actually undefined behavior in C++ and I was wondering how would you type pun instead?

As an example I used a union to type pun two types from two third party libraries with identical layout like this (libAQuaternion and libBQuaternion are the types of those third party libraries which I can't change):

```
struct libAQuaternion {
    double x, y, z, w;
};

void libAFunc(libAQuaternion &p) {
    p.x = p.y = p.z = p.w = 1.;
}

struct libBQuaternion {
    double x, y, z, w;
};

void libBFunc(libBQuaternion &p) {
    p.x = p.y = p.z = p.w = 2.;
}

union myQuat {
    libAQuaternion a;
    libBQuaternion b;
};

int main() {
    myQuat q;
    libAFunc(q.a);
    libBFunc(q.b);
}
```

What would be the standard conforming best solution to this?

Comment: You can't type pun in C++. Doing it is always UB, but some implementations give you certain guarantees IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't allow type punning. Most of the time.

What you wrote is perfectly legal, but there is one potential hazard.

The two quaternions are [standard layout classes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#8) and their [common initial sequence](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#21) is their entirety.  It is thus [legal](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.mem#24) to *read* the member of the other through a union

```
myQuat q = libAQuaternion{1, 0, 0, 0};
std::cout << q.b.x;    // legal
```

We then note that the quaternions can only be written to by either a builtin/trivial assignment or by placement new.

- Using a builtin/trivial assignment on an inactive member (or its member, recursively), [causes the implicit beginning](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.union#5) of the inactive member's lifetime.
- Using a placement new will also begin the member's lifetime.

Thus upon writing to a quaternion, either its lifetime already begun, or it will begin.

Reading and writing is together called accessing, and the [strict-aliasing rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#11) forbids accessing something with another type, which is what forbids type-punning. But since we just proved that accessing either quaternions is well-defined, this is the one exception where type-punning is indeed legal.

The one hazard is when the library function writes partially to the quaternion

```
void someFunc(libBQuaternion& q)
{
    q.x = 1;
}

myQuat q = libAQuaternion{1, 0, 0, 0};
someFunc(q.b);
std::cout << q.a.y;    // UB
```

Unfortunately, `q.a.y` is uninitialized and therefore reading it is undefined behaviour.

However, given all the previous rules and the reason behind having uninitialized variables is efficiency, it is quite unlikely compilers will take advantage of the UB and "miscompile".

Comment: +1 you answered while I was typing pretty much the same thing. So let me just mention this talk from CppCon 2017, that discusses this problem and type punning in general: [Scott Schurr “Type Punning in C++17: Avoiding Pun-defined Behavior”](https://youtu.be/sCjZuvtJd-k?t=3117)

Comment: And if I understand standard layout classes correct, it shouldn't matter if those structs have constructors or non-virtual member functions, cause I left those out for simplification assuming they wouldn't matter..

Comment: @MichaelMahn Yes indeed. You could put in a check to make sure `static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<libAQuaternion>);`

Comment: @besc I skimmed through the video and found Scott Schurr made a mistake: you can't _access_ an inactive member (given the prerequisites), you can only _read_ it.

Comment: @PasserBy After rewatching and re-reading the standard, I agree that Schurr’s use of *access* is misleading. In his defense, he never comes right out and says that writes are ok; and my impression is that he *wants* to talk about reads only. But it’s easy to misunderstand – I certainly did when I watched it the first time.

Answer (score 3):

> What be the standard conforming best solution to this?

Write a function to convert from one quaternion to the other.

```
libBQuaternion convert(const libAQuaternion &Quat) {
  return{Quat.x, Quat.y, Quat.z, Quat.w};
}

libAQuaternion convert(const libBQuaternion &Quat) {
  return{Quat.x, Quat.y, Quat.z, Quat.w};
}

// or template if you want to
template<typename T, typename U>
T convertTo(U &&Quat) {
  return{Quat.x, Quat.y, Quat.z, Quat.w};
}
```

Any optimizer should be able to optimize this away completely, so there should be no performance penalty.

But this will be a problem if there is a function taking one such class by lvalue ref. You would need to create a new object of the appropriate class, pass that and then reassign the correct values to the original struct. I guess you could make a function for this, but IMO the cleanest way would be to change the signature of the function to take the individual values by lvalue ref, but that is not always possible.

There is just no way of doing type punning in C++ without invoking UB.

Comment: Now this won't work when passing non-const-qualified reference as OP does in both `libAFunc` and `libBFunc`.

Comment: How would you use this then? I added this and changed my main to int main() {
 libAQuaternion a;
 libAFunc(a);
 libBFunc(convert(a));
}
But I get a compiler error now: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘libBQuaternion&’ from an rvalue of type ‘libBQuaternion’

Comment: @Micheal Yeah, you need to create a new object, pass that in and then assign the updated values to the original object.

Comment: @VTT That's true, but there is no way around that AFAIK. Except taking individual values by ref instead of the class

Comment: When combining libraries for 3d geometry, visualization, and simulation, you mostly end up in a solution like this as every library often defines its own linear algebra. (The only lucky exception is if they either are based all on a separate lib for this (e.g. Eigen), or they are all written by yourself.) One add.: you could even overload `operator=()` for the conversion if you like it. This makes code a bit more elegant but hides the fact that a conversion happens. IMHO, it cannot hurt to make conversions in code explicit (to prevent overlooking/forgetting about this fact).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class D, class S>
D bitcpy( S const* s ){
  static_assert( sizeof(S)>=sizeof(D) );
  D r;
  memcpy( &r, s, sizeof(D) );
  return r;
}
union myQuat {
  libAQuaternion a;
  libBQuaternion b;
  void AsA(){
    a = bitcpy<libAQuaternion>(&b);
  }
  void AsB(){
    b = bitcpy<libBQuaternion>(&a);
  }
};
```

You have to keep track of if there is an `A` or a `B` in the union.  To switch call `AsA` or `AsB`; this is a noop at runtime.

I believe the union rules allow activating members via assignment; if I misunderstand the standard or the situation (these are pod types right?) things get a bit trickier.  But I think that doesn't apply here.

Comment: No, they weren't POD. They also had constructors which I left out for simplification.

Comment: @michael standard layout ness and triviality (construction destruction and copy) *matter* here.  You need those details, because they change wmhow you can create/destroy/copy objects.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to type punning is to use `memcpy` from type A to type B. On many platforms `memcpy` is an intrinsic meaning it is implemented by the compiler and therefore may well be optimized away.